# How to properly replace links in mysql database

Tags: mysql

I have a column in my database which contains links. However, after reinstalling an SSL, some of the links are without the `httpS`. So they now look like `http://example.com/this-is-a-link`

I decided to run a query that find links with `http://` and replace them with `https://`

What I tried

```
UPDATE `wp_table`
SET slug = REPLACE(slug, 'http://', 'https://')
WHERE `slug` LIKE '%http://%'
```

Instead, this stripped the links of the http:// so that now the link looks something like `this-is-an-example-link`

Please help me fix this. A fix to replace entire database not just table will be very helpful. (I only know how to update inside a single table). Thanks.

Comment: That should work.. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=5a579d6783ff54893f67f33284ae3937

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh and if from some reason you still want to make it via phpMyAdmin so use this one instead:

```
UPDATE `tableName` SET `columnName` = REPLACE(
    `tableName`.`columnName`,
    "http://",
    "https://"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well a good tool for that is "Better Search Replace" Plugin, I love it because you can delete it after using it so it doesn't affect your site afterwards..
Just search for a term and replace with another, Simple As That, You can also filter the DB rows you want to run the search etc..

About your slugs, This is the way they are built, "-" stands for spaces between any word/keyterm so in that case you can't really delete all dashes in database.. So I recommend restore a backup (You do have a backup right?) and after backup restored just run the search replace from http to https.